# How to use @polkadot/react-components? version issue

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot

I have tried to use `@polkadot/react-components`in React project
[image]

Here, AddressInfo component component is from `@polkadot/react-components`
When I try to use this component, I got this issue
[image]

I'd really appreciate if anyone can help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polkadot/react-components), this package is not intended to be used by others developers.

> WARNING: This is an internal package to polkadot-js/apps so is not inteded (yet) for broad use.

Comment: I'm making new custom UI based on that repository (https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps), but I got above issue
Do you have any idea for using that component (@polkadot/react-components)?
I need to use that component, that's why I'm just forking some feature of polkadot-js/app repository now